# find the multiple occurance of a substring in a string

Tags: php

I want to get the position of a sub string from a string using php. I can use `strpos()`, but it returns only first occurrence. How can I get the positions of multiple occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#108426

```
function strpos_r($haystack, $needle)
{
    if(strlen($needle) > strlen($haystack))
        trigger_error(sprintf("%s: length of argument 2 must be <= argument 1", __FUNCTION__), E_USER_WARNING);

    $seeks = array();
    while($seek = strrpos($haystack, $needle))
    {
        array_push($seeks, $seek);
        $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, $seek);
    }
    return $seeks;
}
```

This will return an array with the position of occurences.

Comment: This function is buggy when *needle* is a prefix of *haystack* as `strpos`returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual, there are such functions in the comments.

```
function strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0, &$results = array()) {                
    $offset = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
    if($offset === false) {
        return $results;            
    } else {
        $results[] = $offset;
        return strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle, ($offset + 1), $results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter of strpos, has a $offset you can use:

```
$positions_of_string = array();
$str_to_find = "string to find";
$str_length = strlen( $str_to_find );
$last_found = 0 - $str_length;

while( false !== $last_found ) {
    $last_found = strpos( $the_string, $str_to_find, $last_found+$str_length );
    if( false !== $last_found )
        $positions_of_strings[] = $last_found;
}
```